# Are there any 3rd party profiler apps for SQL Server 2005+

Tags: sql-server-2005, profiling

I know that's a crazy question. I know I can use the built-in SQL profiler, client statistics, other statistics built into SQL Server (oh just view the query plan) -- but that's all ugly, takes too much time to set up and the results are not intuitive.

What I was hoping for was something like JetBrains DotTrace where you could see hotspots of slow code - but applied to stored procedures.

Let me also add I am working with existing stored procs that are lengthy - some are 10k plus lines. While this is not ideal, I only want to start with refactoring small parts of only the worse performing stored procs - and so I don't have to spend all day looking at performance numbers/timings/etc, I just want a profiler that shows me where in those stored procs the time is being spent (which blocks or lines).

Crazy request, I know - hopefully someone knows something that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [DBSophic's tools](http://www.dbsophic.com/). The free tool helps you analyze a trace you've already collected, and gives recommendations for T-SQL re-writes, schema changes etc., focusing on the most painful parts (regardless of number of lines in modules).

If you [combine their Workload Analyzer with our tool, SQL Sentry Performance Advisor](http://www.sqlsentry.com/solutions-sql-server-qure.asp), you can point it at workload data that we've already collected - so no worry about going and manually collecting your own trace. I wrote [a blog post about this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/04/21/using-qure-workload-optimizer-for-sql-sentry).